# New-WebServiceProxy Authentification fails when username contains a '@' character

Tags: powershell, soap-client

I'm trying to create a proxy to a SOAP service using the [New-WebServiceProxy cmdlet](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135238) with a username containing a `@`character:

```
$webAddr = 'https://MYSERVER?wsdl'
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "MYPASSWORD" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("USER@NAME", $secpasswd)

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $webAddr -Credential $mycreds
```

Somehow, this doesn't work and I receive the following error:

> New-WebServiceProxy : The request failed with HTTP status 401:
>   Authentification failed!.

When I use the same code with a username without an '@' character, the proxy gets created and is working fine. I'm also able to connect to the server with the username containing the `@` character with `C#` when I add the service reference in Visual Studio or by using a browser.

I already tried to escape the username using `System.Uri.EscapeUriString()` and `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode()`without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: A User Principle Name such as `Username@domain.com` uses a @ to separate the name and domain. If this is assuming it's a UPN name it's probably assuming Name is a domain of some sort rather than part of the username.

Comment: Yes, I think thats the issue - but I still need a workaround for that :-/. In fact, the web service (which is not implemented by me) uses the `@` to determine the database it connects to. Imho, this isn't good practice. But I have to deal with it and its possible using C# or using a Browser...

Comment: Confirmed, if I run your script and run `$mycreds.GetNetworkCredential` it's split NAME into a Domain property.

Comment: Okay, do you know any ways to bypass that?

Comment: Grrr... You can correctly set the username in the GetNetworkCredential object but NewWebServiceProxy won't accept a NetworkCredential, and there doesn't appear to be any way of converting it back. Lemme poke around a bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, if you tell it there is no domain it will assume the @ is part of the username:

```
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("\USER@NAME", $secpasswd)
```

Adding the \ does the trick.

Comment: Dude, you are a genius. I will give you the bounty in 18h (cannot do it right now). Can you please tell me how you figured that out?

Comment: =) Good to feel appreciated. I got it through trial and error, exploring the objects through Get-Member showed there wasn't really any way of modifying the object once created so I started messing about with creating the object just running `(Get-Credential).GetNetworkCredential()` and trying a bunch of stuff. After a few attempts I found that the backlash overrode the @